# Executing User-defined SQL Server function in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have this SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Average (@year int)
RETURNS decimal(4,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result as decimal(4,2);
    SET @result = (SELECT AVG(CAST(MilkQuantity AS decimal(4,2))) FROM MilkProduction WHERE YEAR(Date) = @year);
    RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

How do I execute this function in java and what data type do I even bind it to?

This is what I came up with and it works but it seems like I'm coloring outside the lines here:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT dbo.Average(" + year + ")");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println("Average: " + rs.getFloat(""));
```

Comment: This works depending on the database engine. For example, this won't work on oracle.

Comment: I believe this syntax is for MS products only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CallableStatement as below:
`CallableStatement stmt = null;
        String sql = "begin ? := Average(?); end;";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try { 
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, INT);
            stmt.setString(2, "VALUE");
            stmt.execute();
            }
Catch(){ ....}`